# 2D Rotated rectangle contains point calculation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math

My issue is that I've been trying to check if a rectangle that is rotated by a certain amount of degrees contain a point, but I wasn't able to calculate that after many attempts with the help of some code samples and examples that I've found online.

What I got is the rectangle (X, Y, Width, Height, Rotation) and the point (X, Y) and I've been trying to create a simple function that lets me instantly calculate that, which would be something something like this:

```
public bool Contains(Rect Rectangle, float RectangleRotation, Point PointToCheck);
```

But as I mentioned, I wasn't able to do so, those mathematical calculations that include some formulas I found online are way too much for me to understand.

Could someone help me with calculating this? If you could provide the calculation in C# code form (not formulas) then that would be great! Thanks.

PS: Using the 2D Physics Engine that is available in Unity3D is not a option, my rectangle is not associated with a gameobject that I could attach a 2D collision component to, I need to do this mathematically without the involvement of gameobjects or components.

Edit: I forgot to mention, the rectangle is being rotated by the middle of the rectangle (center/origin).

Comment: and the rectangle rotates about what? its midpoint, one of its edges, the origin of coordinates? show your attempt(s) so we could have a look what's wrong. `bool` makes more sense as the return type than `void` :)

Comment: The easiest way is probably to transform the problem into an easier one, by moving and rotating the rectangle and point together so that the rectangle begins at the origin. Then you just have to check if the transformed point is above the origin and below the width and height.

Comment: @dlatikay I edited my question, the rotation happens by the middle (center/origin) of the rectangle.

Comment: Read [the second answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/190373).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than checking if the point is in a rotated rectangle, just apply the opposite of the rotation to the point and check if the point is in a normal rectangle. In other words, change your perspective by rotating everything by `-RectangleRotation`, so that the rectangle does not appear rotated at all.

```
public bool Contains(Rect rect, float rectAngle, Point point)
{
    // rotate around rectangle center by -rectAngle
    var s = Math.Sin(-rectAngle);
    var c = Math.Cos(-rectAngle);

    // set origin to rect center
    var newPoint = point - rect.center;
    // rotate
    newPoint = new Point(newPoint.x * c - newPoint.y * s, newPoint.x * s + newPoint.y * c);
    // put origin back
    newPoint = newPoint + rect.center;

    // check if our transformed point is in the rectangle, which is no longer
    // rotated relative to the point

    return newPoint.x >= rect.xMin && newPoint.x <= rect.xMax && newPoint.y >= rect.yMin && newPoint.y <= rect.yMax;
}
```

Comment: @InBetween I didn't know about this, thanks. However, OP said they were overwhelmed by whatever they found when they did a Google search, and this solution is the easiest one to understand

Comment: Yes, it looks like its working, I quickly tested it out and it looks to be a little bit inaccurate, I don't need the point to be on a corner for example and it returns true, but it does mostly work! I am still testing things out, if everything is fine I'll mark the answer as the solution. 

@InBetween I did find that formula when I was trying to do this my self, but I wasn't able to understand of what kind of calculation its telling me to do, I don't know what the ∧ for example suppose to be. It also needs 4 corners, which I don't have and I would have to calculate.

Comment: I would like to mention that when I am drawing the rectangle to something so I can visually see it, its rendered with the use of a rotation matrix, which I create like this:

Matrix.CreateRotationZ(RectangleRotation);

So the solution might actually be 100% working and its just a visual problem!

Comment: @TheMisteryMan ∧ is an alternative symbol for the *cross-product* ([`Vector3.Cross`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Cross.html)). Do not confuse it with `^` in C# (XOR).